# Install a new package from requirement.txt without upgrading the dependencies which are already satisfied

Tags: python, pip

I am using requirement.txt to specify the package dependencies that are used in my python application. And everything seems to work fine for packages of which either there are no internal dependencies or for the one using the package dependencies which are not already installed.

The issue occurs when i try to install a package which has a nested dependency on some other package and an older version of this package is already installed.

I know i can avoid this while installing a package manually bu using `pip install -U --no-deps <package_name>`. I want to understand how to do this using the requirement.txt as the deployment and requirement installation is an automated process.

**Note:**

The already installed package is not something i am directly using in my project but is part of a different project on the same server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the dependency satisfied by the older version?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency resolution is a fairly complicated problem. A requirements.txt just specifies your dependencies with optional version ranges. If you want to "lock" your transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in place you would have to produce a requirements.txt that contains exact versions of every package you install with something like `pip freeze`. This doesn't solve the problem but it would at least point out to you on an install which dependencies conflict so that you can manually pick the right versions.

That being said the new (as of writing) officially supported tool for managing application dependencies is [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This tool will both manage the exact versions of transitive dependencies for you (so you won't have to maintain a "requirements.txt" manually) and it will isolate the packages that your code requires from the rest of the system. (It does this using the virtualenv tool under the hood). This isolation should fix your problems with breaking a colocated project since your project can have different versions of libraries than the rest of the system.

(TL;DR Try using Pipenv and see if your problem just disappears)